# Facebook Graph API Not Accepting Thumbnail

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, thumbnails, image, restfb

I am attempting to upload a link/thumbnail combination to my feed using RestFB.  The post works, but the thumbnail image is not showing up.  Here is the link I am trying:

http://www.suntimes.com/news/steinberg/10065535-452/motion-disorder-hard-to-diagnose.html

And this is the thumbnail:

```
    http://www.suntimes.com/csp/cms/sites/dt.common.streams.StreamServer.cls?STREAMOID=
    Wr0K2P_9k6qs__jFJeDrpc$daE2N3K4ZzOUsqbU5sYtFPrZXIcOdljXl6kaN8Wt0WCsjLu883Ygn4B49Lvm
    9bPe2QeMKQdVeZmXF$9l$4uCZ8QDXhaHEp3rvzXRJFdy0KqPHLoMevcTLo3h8xh70Y6N_U_CryOsw6FTOdK
    L_jpQ-&CONTENTTYPE=image/jpeg
```

Like I said, the thumbnail is not showing up in the feed.  I've also tried using curl from the command line, here is the curl request:

```
    curl 
    -d "message=fake message" 
    -d "link=http://www.suntimes.com/news/steinberg/10065535-452/motion-disorder-hard-to-diagnose.html"
    -d "picture=http://www.suntimes.com/csp/cms/sites/dt.common.streams.StreamServer.
    cls?STREAMOID=HDrMcg9mtadcR0rFJSBgf8$daE2N3K4ZzOUsqbU5sYvO5PITQX2u2Lo66c2ru9kMWCs
    jLu883Ygn4B49Lvm9bPe2QeMKQdVeZmXF$9l$4uCZ8QDXhaHEp3rvzXRJFdy0KqPHLoMevcTLo3h8xh70
    Y6N_U_CryOsw6FTOdKL_jpQ-&CONTENTTYPE=image/jpeg" 
    "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"
```

Any ideas?  Otherwise, I will be submitting a bug to Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's a Facebook bug, thanks nobody.